# Alamofire json parsing

Tags: ios, swift3

```
self.manager!.request( url+"FindNearestClasses", method: .post, parameters: requestDictionary, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,headers: headers
            ).responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value)
        }
```

The problem I have the json returned to me is like below. How can I parse it by number that is get array, and then after array each read first second third and fourth numbers.

[ 
 [
   "1",
   "2",
   "3",
    4],
  [
   "5",
   "6",
   "7",
    8]
]

Answer (score 0):

```
let myjson = [ [ "1", "2", "3", "4"], [ "5", "6", "7", "8"] ]
let myInt = Int(myjson[0].first as! String) 
/* 
let i = 0
let j = 0
let myInt = Int(myjson[i][j] as! String) 
i stands for the which array 0 or 1 in this case. j stands for the value inside that array. 

*/
print(myInt)
```

This will print `1` as Int, if you want to loop through entire array then use for loop.

```
for myi in myjson{
for myj in myi {
    print(myj) // this will print all the contents of both array.
 }
}
```

To convert string to Int, use `_ = Int(myjson[i][j] as! String)`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a tool to map the response into swift objects, an example is Object mapper: https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

```
import AlamofireObjectMapper

let URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/d8bb95982be8a11a2308e779bb9a9707ebe42ede/sample_json"
Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<WeatherResponse>) in

let weatherResponse = response.result.value
print(weatherResponse?.location)

 if let threeDayForecast = weatherResponse?.threeDayForecast {
     for forecast in threeDayForecast {
        print(forecast.day)
        print(forecast.temperature)           
     }
  }
}
```